# ldappaswordmodify doesn't accept -w - option

Tags: oracle, opends

I use OpenDS package ( This is a very great LDAP soft) and I've got tiny problem with an option of ldappasswordmodify command

```
:~# ldappasswordmodify --version
OpenDS Directory Server 2.2.0
Build 20091123144827Z
--
           Name                 Build number         Revision number     
Extension: snmp-mib2605         2.2.0                6181        

~# ldappasswordmodify -h localhost -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w -  -a "dn:uid=user,ou=People,dc=acme,dc=org"An error occurred while attempting to connect to the Directory Server:  The
simple bind attempt failed
:~# ldappasswordmodify -h localhost -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w xxxxxxx  -a "dn:uid=user,ou=People,dc=acme,dc=org"
The LDAP password modify operation was successful
Generated Password:  F8F2R1W6V
```

I did research and I found this on the Oracle Site : 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19623-01/820-6171/ldappasswordmodify.html

```
-w, --bindPassword bindPassword

    Use the bind password when authenticating to the directory server. This option can be used for simple authentication as well as password-based SASL mechanisms. This option must not be used in conjunction with --bindPasswordFile. To prompt for the password, type -w -.
```

What I did wrong?
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this line working :

```
    :~# read -s A ; ldappasswordmodify -h localhost -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w $A  -a "dn:uid=user,ou=People,dc=acme,dc=org"  
The LDAP password modify operation was successful 
Generated Password:  F8F2R1W6V
```

Thanks anyway